# Can we provide different config for different database instance?

Tags: mongodb, configuration

I have created a config file of mongodb at path /etc/db where I have enabled auth. While starting the mongod process when i provide --config with it the port 27017 start with auth enabled otherwise auth will be disabled.
I want to start 2 different port with different config file how can i do it.
Currently the two different instance will be started.

```
mongod --storageEngine wiredTiger --dbpath "./digv" --port 27029
```

when i provide --config option then it gives the error.

```
digvijay@digvijay-Vostro-3558:~$ mongod --config mongod.conf  --storageEngine wiredTiger --dbpath "./digv" --port 27029

2019-04-16T12:01:29.994+0530 F CONTROL  [main] Failed global initialization: FileNotOpen: Failed to open "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"
```

Can i provide different config file and how?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the actual error message you are getting. You can definitely start two `mongod` instances with different `--config` paths. You have to ensure instances on the same host do not share configuration values for `dbPath`, `logpath`, or `bindIp` + `port` combinations since each instance needs exclusive access to those resources. If you want to provide a different config file, you could always copy an existing config and modify it to suit.

Comment: Provided the error in the question

Comment: The error message indicates the MongoDB log file cannot be opened. If you are sharing this `mongod.conf` with another instance, both cannot have the same settings for `logpath`. I suspect you want to make a copy of your MongoDB config file (eg `cp mongod.conf mongod-27029.conf`), make all of your edits in the copied config, and then start your second instance as `mongod --config mongod-27029.conf`. It is better to include all of the optoins in the config file (for consistency) rather than mixing a config file with command line options.